# Rails: validates_uniqueness_of with conditions not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have a model that uses an 'active' flag to soft-delete items instead of destroying them. The model has a 'name' property, which must be unique among active items.  I was trying to use the `conditions` modifier with `validates_uniqueness_of`, but it still seems to be checking for uniqueness across both active and inactive items.  What am I doing wrong?

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :active
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, conditions: -> { where(active:true) }

end
```

Comment: the only problem with doing something like this is when you then want to re-activate an inactive Foo, but you can't because it would be invalid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `scope` and `if` modifiers in conjunction for this:

```
scope :active, where(:active => true)
validates :name, :uniqueness => {:message => 'That name is in use', :if => :active?, :scope => :active}
```

This will cause only items that are active to trigger the validation, and the validation will consider uniqueness only among items that are active.

I have confirmed that this works in Rails 3 and 4.

Answer (score 4):

If the scope differs from the conditions, you can apply the scope within those conditions by adding a conditions key to the uniqueness object:

```ruby
scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }

validates :active, uniqueness: {
  scope: :name,
  message: 'name is in use',
  conditions: -> { active }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
validates :active, :uniqueness => { :scope => :name, :message => 'name is in use'}, :if => :active
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me —

```
validates_uniqueness_of :asset_id, scope: :source,
                        conditions: -> { where.not(source: :azure) },
                        :allow_nil => true, :allow_blank => true,
                        message: "has already been taken with this source."
```